# If you graph $z = xy$ then what does the level set c = xy look like , say c = 3 as for example?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I can graph $z = xy$ but what does the level set look like that is 3 = xy?  I am having trouble picturing it.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%3Dxy

Comment: If you think of the graph $z = xy$ as a surface "hovering" over the $x$-$y$ plane, then when you say $c = xy$, this would trace in the $x$-$y$ plane a curve denoting that the point "above" (in the sense the points in the hovering surface) are exactly at height $c$. I sometime like to see this as a "shadow" of the contour-line on the surface that lies exactly at height $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$xy=3$ will be a rectangular hyperbola, just like other curves of the form $xy=\text{constant}$.

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes but can you show what F(z) = xy looks like. I am trying to get an intuition for how a hyperbola jumps out of what might be a saddle shape with the level curve looking from the top down. I am having an intuition problem trying to picture how the above level curve is produced from the graph of f(z) = xy so it stands to reason I need to look at the graph of z = xy . no?